# Design principle for proxy objects or different approach

Tags: architecture, rust

#### Main Problem:

I write a cli application to communicate with a http-server. The Server provides me with several endpoints and some functions under these endpoints (eg. `/todo/add`, `/other_endpoint/del`). Access to the library should represent these endpoints (eg `master.todo.add(...)`, `master.other_endpoint.del(...)`).

My first attemp was to add the `Master` as reference to all endpoint objects.

```
struct Todo {
    m: Master
}
```

The `Master` holds objects to all endpoints

```
struct Master {
    todo: Todo,
    other_endpoint: OtherEndpoint,
    server: Server,
}
```

`Master` holds a `server` object to communicate with the http-server. So endpoint objects can call this server object via `self.master.server.communicate()`.

But I have driven my rust(y) car against a `recursive type 'Master' has infinite size`. After that I have tried a `m: &'a Master` with all definitions of the lifetimes. But without success.

I have now two questions:

1. What do I have to do to get this to work?
2. Does another design exist (maybe a nicer one) to get this done?

Edit:

- The question isn't resolved with [Why are recursive struct types illegal in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust) as I ask about the design around this problem.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler tells you `Todo` and `Master` are recursive types and thus have infinite size and you need to

> insert indirection (e.g., a `Box`, `Rc`, or `&`) at some point

So you basically have three options:

1. Hold `Master` as reference in `Todo`

This introduces lifetimes to your structs but should be possible:

```
struct Server {}

struct Todo<'a> {
    m: &'a Master<'a>
}

struct Master<'a> {
    todo: Todo<'a>,
    server: Server,
}
```

2. `box` `master`

Looks simpler and you do not run into lifetime issues from the beginning on. Keep in mind though, that `box` have an implicit `'static` lifetime. You may need to change that.

```
struct Server {}

struct Todo{
    m: Box<Master> // or if 'static is not what you need Box<Master + 'a>
}

struct Master {
    todo: Todo,
    server: Server,
}
```

3. The last option presented to you by the compiler is a reference counted pointer to `Master`

Reference counting introduces a small runtime overhead. But when you're dealing with http-requests that should be negligible.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
struct Server {}

struct Todo{
    m: Rc<Master>
}

struct Master {
    todo: Todo,
    server: Server,
}
```

These are your three basic options. I would recommend you to play with them to get to know them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had some other issues, but the problem which I have described was answered. Thanks @Jdemler.