# Recursive data type that doesn't care about owning substructure

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

I often want to define recursive data type in Rust. We need some level of indirection to avoid having a type with unbounded size. The classic solution is to use `Box` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6d02de3b7acfb0fac481e52a70471d3e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
enum IntList {
    Empty,
    Cons(i32, Box<IntList>),
}
```

The problem I have with this it that it requires that the list own its own tail. This means you can't have space sharing between two lists that share a tail because both want to own it. You could use a borrowed reference ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=71f3067fd404f39265ad689d3cf0646c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
enum IntList<'a> {
    Empty,
    Cons(i32, &'a IntList<'a>),
}
```

But then it's hard to create a list because it's not allowed to own its own tail.

**Is there a way to have the list not care whether or not it owns the tail?** That way I could have one list own the tail and another list have a reference to that same list as its tail.

#### My Attempt

My first thought was to use `Cow` for this purpose, but I couldn't get it to work. This is what I tried ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3e1279418da26edb0bc0178297e59606&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum IntList<'a> {
    Empty,
    Cons(i32, Cow<'a, IntList<'a>),
}
```

but it fails with error

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `IntList<'a>: std::marker::Sized`
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |   Cons(i32, Cow<'a, IntList<'a>>),
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::borrow::ToOwned` for `IntList<'a>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::borrow::Cow<'a, IntList<'a>>`
  = note: no field of an enum variant may have a dynamically sized type
```

Comment: The error message is confusing, but you're trying to create a type of infinite size. See [Why are recursive struct types illegal in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust) Wrapping the `Cow` in a `Box` is one way to fix that.

Comment: I get that types of infinite size are bad, but my understand was that a `Cow<'a, IntList<'a>>` represents either a `Box<IntList<'a>>` or a `&'a IntList<'a>`, both of which have a level of indirection and so aren't infinite.

Comment: @JJW5432 `Cow` doesn't box. It will be either `IntList<'a>` or `&'a IntList<'a>`.

Comment: Then how come it "boxes" for strings? It's either `&str` or `String` which is roughly `Box<str>` (correct me if that's not true). That's the behavior I'm going for, either a `Box<IntList<'a>>` or a `&'a IntList<'a>`.

Comment: It also does the same for `[T]` and `Vec<T>`. I think this happens in the [`ToOwned` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html). Should I add a custom implementation of that trait? I tried it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2309b6193927058394a52e5b0391f550&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) but ran into similar troubles.

Comment: *`String` which is roughly `Box<str>`* — it is not. `String` has a capacity, for starters.

Comment: *either a `Box<IntList<'a>>` or a `&'a IntList<'a>`* — then make that enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a data type kind of like `Cow` that I called `Cowish`. If there is already something like this out there, please let me know!

```
pub enum Cowish<'a, T, O>
where
    T: 'a,
{
    Borrowed(&'a T),
    Owned(O),
}

impl<'a, T, O> Borrow<T> for Cowish<'a, T, O>
where
    T: 'a,
    O: Borrow<T>,
{
    fn borrow(&self) -> &T {
        match self {
            Borrowed(b) => b,
            Owned(o) => o.borrow(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, O> Cowish<'a, T, O>
where
    T: ToOwned<Owned=O> + 'a,
    O: Borrow<T>,
{
    pub fn into_owned(self) -> O {
        match self {
            Borrowed(b) => b.to_owned(),
            Owned(o) => o,
        }
    }
}
```

Using that, I can do what I wanted:

```
enum IntList<'a> {
    Empty,
    Cons(i32, Cowish<'a, IntList<'a>, Box<IntList<'a>>>),
}
```

A larger example can be found [here](https://github.com/jbaum98/sharing-list).

Comment: _"If there is already something like this out there, please let me know!"_ —It's not exactly the same, but you can use the [`either` crate](https://crates.io/crates/either). The result might be something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0853ce9270e5032d59f252002b2ed33d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Answer (score 0):

This may be too old but just for the record, if you want to make a linked list you can use `std::rc::Rc`. It's just like `Box`, but you can have more than one reference to a single object. The only caveat is that you can't mutate the list once it's enclosed in Rc. Here is an example from the [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html):

```
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Rc<List>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(Cons(5, Rc::new(Cons(10, Rc::new(Nil))))); // [10, 5]
    let b = Cons(3, Rc::clone(&a)); // [10, 5, 3]
    let c = Cons(4, Rc::clone(&a)); // [10, 5, 4]
}
```