# Why can't we use RefCell for recursive data structures?

Tags: rust

Why can't we use `RefCell` for recursive data structures in Rust?

Invalid:

```
enum List {
    Cons(i32, RefCell<List>),
    Nil,
}
```

Valid:

```
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Rc<List>), // or Box<List>
    Nil,
}
```

Comment: Is this similar enough to [Why are recursive struct types illegal in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust) that it can be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: This question is different. I understand why recursive types are invalid and that we can solve that using indirection. But I assume all smart pointers provide indirection since, after all, they are pointers. So my question is is why doesn't RefCell provide indirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RefCell` contains the object inside, wrapping it, it's **not** a heap allocated value. That's why the compiler says "recursive without indirection": `RefCell` is not an indirection.

`Box` and `Rc`, on the other hand, contain a reference to an object allocated somewhere else, and therefore are *indirections*.

Without an indirection, the `List` enum ends up being infinite since every `Cons` contains a full `List` enum inside its `RefCell`.

You can not do recursive data structures that contain themselves as values, only as pointers or references.