# How can I use nested structs?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and for the first time I'm writing this sort of code:

[PLAYGROUND HERE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=377f57609cc18ed7c69134ae3b7ed61c)

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    #[derive(Default, Clone)]
    pub struct Coach {
        id: Option<i64>,
        name: String,
        team: Option<Team>
    }

    #[derive(Default, Clone)]
    pub struct Team {
        id: Option<i64>,
        name: String,
        coach: Option<Coach>
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0072]: recursive type `Coach` has infinite size
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     pub struct Coach {
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ recursive type has infinite size
...
7 |         team: Option<Team>
  |               ------------ recursive without indirection
  |
help: insert some indirection (e.g., a `Box`, `Rc`, or `&`) to make `Coach` representable
  |
7 |         team: Option<Box<Team>>
  |                      ++++    +

error[E0072]: recursive type `Team` has infinite size
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     pub struct Team {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ recursive type has infinite size
...
14 |         coach: Option<Coach>
   |                ------------- recursive without indirection
   |
help: insert some indirection (e.g., a `Box`, `Rc`, or `&`) to make `Team` representable
   |
14 |         coach: Option<Box<Coach>>
   |                       ++++     +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0072`.
```

Coming from Go where something like this is easily possible, what is Rust idiomatic code?

Comment: The compiler is literally telling you what to do.

Comment: Yeah, but what is the idiomatic way of doing it? Box or lifetimes for example?

Comment: Just like the compiler is telling you.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I wouldn't overgeneralize on this, because the compiler does give nonsensical instructions in certain situations. But for this specific case, I'd agree that adding `Box` is the correct way to go.

Comment: @FredHors `Box` and lifetimes are not interchangeable. They are completely separate concepts that don't even go in the same direction. You probably mean references.

Comment: Yeah, as explained in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust#comment102377335_25296420 I would like to not allocate on the heap...

Comment: @FredHors Whatever you are trying to achieve with it, I'm 99% sure that you are going the wrong direction. If you really do want this, you probably want weak RC pointers. Everything else is either almost impossible to create, or prone to leaking memory. Remember, Rust does not have a garbage collector like many other languages, Rust explicitly made the decision to not have a runtime.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Voting to reopen because the linked answer does not say anything about recursive **object** references (object a referencing object b referencing object a), it only states **struct** references (object a referencing object b of the same type). There are solutions to what he is trying to do, like storing the objects as `Rc` somewhere and having them reference each other through `Weak`.

Comment: @Finomnis I don't know what he is trying to do. It may be cyclic data structure or not.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The names are `coach` and `team`. I'd argue it is very simply to infer that it is a cyclic reference. Which the duplicate question does in fact ask about, but neither answer even mentions it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman On the other hand, what I just said probably in fact does mean that it is a duplicate. There's just a proper answer missing there. I might add it.

Comment: I'll wait for a correct answer to this @Finomnis because you're right: that answer does not talk about recursive structs.

Comment: @FredHors Added an answer that talks about `Rc` and `Weak` in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131079/2902833).

Comment: @FredHors I have to correct your terminology though, the answer does very much talk about recursive structs. It does not talk about cyclic references. There's a fine but important difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

add `Box`, since it's a "pointer"

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    #[derive(Default, Clone)]
    pub struct Coach {
        id: Option<i64>,
        name: String,
        team: Option<Box<Team>>
    }

    #[derive(Default, Clone)]
    pub struct Team {
        id: Option<i64>,
        name: String,
        coach: Option<Box<Coach>>
    }
}
```

you could ref to https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-layout.html?highlight=box#basic-data-layout

Comment: Sotty, I updated the question using the `Option<>`. Can you re-cehck please?

Comment: Be aware that while this is possible to define, it doesn't make much sense to use it. Once created it would be impossible to use. You will never be able to create a `Coach` who owns his `Team` which owns him back. Creating such objects would force you to drop all references to them, essentially leaking them.

Comment: @Finomnis can I ask you what do you suggest?

Comment: @FredHors If you want to pursuit the path you are on, a combination of `Rc`, `Weak` and `RefCell`. But I'd argue that it would be better to lay out your data structures in a way so this isn't required. But that probably depends on the exact problem you have.

Comment: @Finomnis yeah, this is what I'm trying to understand: how to lay out my data structures. Can you point me in a direction, please? Something like CRUD with multiple (nested) entities...

Comment: Not sure, I'm missing context here. Maybe create a new question with more detail? Maybe here, or maybe on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.